# Cyclomatic Complexity Violation: Function should have complexity 10 or less: currently complexity equals 13 (cyclomatic_complexity)

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, swiftlint

I have the following code in swift3 and i am using swift lint for linting the code. The code is given as follows:

```
    func selectedMenuInLoggedOutState(sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
      if let menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 0) {
        self.changeGuestViewController(menu)
      }
    case 2:
      if let menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 1) {
        self.changeGuestViewController(menu)
      }
    case 3:
      if let menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 2) {
        self.changeGuestViewController(menu)
      }
    case 4:
      if let menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 3) {
        self.changeGuestViewController(menu)
      }
    case 5:
      if let menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 4) {
        self.changeGuestViewController(menu)
      }
    case 6:
      if let menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 5) {
        self.changeGuestViewController(menu)
      }
    default:
      break
    }
  }
```

The swift lint generates a "Cyclomatic Complexity Violation" warning. Why did this warning occur and how does one resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The warning occurs because your function is too complex as defined by the [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) which essentially counts the number of decisions that need to be made.

A simple way to avoid it in this particular case would be with some simple math:

```
func selectedMenuInLoggedOutState(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: sender.tag - 1) else { return }
    self.changeGuestViewController(menu)
}
```

Comment: Yea, a strong argument can be made that CC should ignore switch/case statements and only count if statements.

Comment: I agree; there is a big difference between a switch and a bunch of `if/elseif/else` statements

Comment: @DanielT. So should i replace the whole switch statement with the single line code that you gave?

Comment: On reflection, I don't think the "math" solution is so bad in this case.  You can use it or try my simplified switch; which ever you like

Comment: I updated with a guard statement to protect against bad tags. Yes @ChelseaShawra, you can replace the whole function with this simpler code.

Comment: Why do your UIButton tags start at 1 rather than 0 anyway?

Comment: @WilliamGP there's a deeper question here of why anyone would use tags at all in UIViews but ‍♂️

Answer (score 63):

The method is **too complex**. But instead of rewriting the code, you could exclude `switches` from the `cyclomatic_complexity` calculation *(since they are perfectly readable)* like this:

```
cyclomatic_complexity:
  ignores_case_statements: true
```

Comment: I like this solution. I do not want to change my case statements.

Comment: how do you discover the options provided by a linter rule?

Comment: If you type run `swiftlint rules` it will list all the current rules for your project - the last column should contain the options.

Answer (score 20):

You can disable swiftlint warnings in code like this:

```
// swiftlint:disable cyclomatic_complexity
func selectedMenuInLoggedOutState(sender: UIButton) {
    ...
}
// swiftlint:enable cyclomatic_complexity
```

or, if you want to explicitly just disable the next swiftlint warning:

```
// swiftlint:disable:next cyclomatic_complexity
func selectedMenuInLoggedOutState(sender: UIButton) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your complexity by eliminating the repeated `if let` statements:

```
func selectedMenuInLoggedOutState(sender: UIButton) {

    let menu: MenuType?

    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
     menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 0)
    case 2:
     menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 1) 
    case 3:
     menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 2) 
    case 4:
      menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 3) 
    case 5:
      menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 4)   
    case 6:
      menu = LeftGuestMenu(rawValue: 5) 
    default:
      menu=nil
    }

    if let menu = menu {
       self.changeGuestViewController(menu)
    }
  }
```

Comment: it shows the error constant menu used before being initialised

Comment: This code has a CC of 8 which avoids the warning, but just barely. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In case if you don't want to change your logic, follow below.
Add "cyclomatic_complexity:" property and set warning value in .swiftlint.yml file.

cyclomatic_complexity:
warning: 25

Note: Here setting warning value means, increasing the number of linearly independent paths. You can set your own value.